# Recreate SVN repository from combination of old backup + most recent working copy on a desktop

Tags: svn

I inherited a situation where I was able to find an instance of the repository files and I know there was one developer, so his PC had the most recent working version.

Is there a way to put the repository file back in place and then checkin to the repository to catch up from the PC.

It's pretty likely that the copy of the repository is NOT the most recent copy that the PC was pulled from due to a catastrophic RAID configuration corruption on the server.  I'm afraid SVN won't let me because the PC copy is based of a later checkout.

Forgive me if I'm using the wrong SVN terminology (like checkin/checkout) since it's been a minute since I've used SVN (been using Git for last 6 years).

I looked at this article and a similar one but these are working from a completely lost repository:

[Recreate subversion repository from svn client checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104753/recreate-subversion-repository-from-svn-client-checkout)

So after pondering for a while I was thinking about doing this:

- restore the repository
- check out the repository somewhere new
- take the files from the previous developer's PC and copy them to the new pc
- verify changes and check in to repository

Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: Your plan is good. There is no way to recover all in-between revisions.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing and it seems to have worked fine:

- restore the repository
- I found the working copy from the previous developer's virtual machine so I copied it to a separate directory on my computer
- compare that working copy with the restored repository
- check in the few newer files in the working copy back into the repository.
- compare my working copy that I still had sitting on my computer as a sanity check to make sure everything looked OK

Yet another disaster averted.